# Java - Apache POI Integer Validation

Tags: java, validation, apache-poi

```
XSSFDataValidationHelper dvHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(
                destinationSheet);
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dvHelper
                .createIntegerConstraint(OperatorType.EQUAL, "0", "10");
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(7,
                destinationSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1, 9, destinationSheet
                        .getRow(0).getLastCellNum());
XSSFDataValidation validation = (XSSFDataValidation) dvHelper
                .createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);

validation.setErrorStyle(ErrorStyle.STOP);
validation.createErrorBox("Error", "Only numeric values are allowed");

destinationSheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

I used the code above which doesn't work and still accepts anything on the cell. If I am right, this line is the culprit.

```
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dvHelper
                    .createIntegerConstraint(OperatorType.EQUAL, "0", "10");
```

Basically, I want the cells from the Cell range to accept only 0 and 10 and restrict alphabet character. I also tried `OperatorType.BETWEEN` but no luck.

Here's my reference. [Busy Developer](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Validation)

Comment: First rule of asking for help: Define what you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: Doesn't work could mean: After I save the file and open it in Excel (1) It accepts anything in that cell; (2) It accepts nothing in that cell; (3) When I type into the cell sparks shoot out from the keyboard; (4) Oh wait, you mean I have to open it in Excel first?

Comment: It actually accepts anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code doesn't show the error whenever the user enters an invalid data.

```
XSSFDataValidationHelper dvHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(
                destinationSheet);
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dvHelper
                .createIntegerConstraint(OperatorType.EQUAL, "0", "10");
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(7,
                destinationSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1, 9, destinationSheet
                        .getRow(0).getLastCellNum());
XSSFDataValidation validation = (XSSFDataValidation) dvHelper
                .createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);

validation.setErrorStyle(ErrorStyle.STOP);
validation.createErrorBox("Error", "Only numeric values are allowed");
validation.setShowErrorBox(true); // The code is missing this line

destinationSheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

The implementation in XSSF is different from HSSF which on the other hand doesn't need the line `validation.setShowErrorBox(true);` to work. I've used HSSF in my previous implementation which results to not setting the `showErrorBox` to `true`.